# How to compile the Linux kernel to be as small as possible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on a side project which requires me to configure and compile a tiny Linux System based on Ubuntu.

The result should be a tiny OS with the following features:

- A Bootloader
- A Kernel
- A Process
- A Thread
- Miscellaneous (if possible)
- A File System
- Virtual memory
- A Console

I read lots of documents about it, one of them being: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~okeefe/p2b/buildMin/buildMin.html#toc3

I deleted the file system, and recompiled the kernel using `make xconfig`. I tried to deactivate modules and configurations many times, but it's not working for me.

How can I configure the kernel for the OS with only the features I listed above? What options can I disable or enable while still having a working system?

Comment: Please be specific when describing what you tried, what the result was and what your problem is. "It's not working" is not specific enough and makes it difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~okeefe/p2b/buildMin/buildMin.html#toc3 is 15 years old. You may want to find a more recent tutorial.

Comment: Try `make localconfig` (or consorts) to disable a huge swath of hardware not present in your system and reduce it from there.

Comment: @AlanAu I tried to use `make allnoconfig` to disable all config as possible to make tiny kernel. But I can't boot, just I see: Loading init ramdisk...

Comment: @pts thank you. I find a lots of docs ...

Comment: @tstenner thank you a lots. I will try. I don't know what options to active for the "Thread", "Virtual memory", .. :(

Answer (score 2):

try Linux From Scratch. It is a step by step approach on building a minimal Linux system from which you can evolve later on. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Having the Kernel very small is not important for Ubuntu, so maybe choosing Ubuntu is part of your problem. I would use as starting point what OpenWRT does. They do a good work making the Kernel small and it is easy to get started. [OpenWrt Buildroot – Usage](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build)

Answer (score 0):

Use Gentoo Linux distribution - it's great for practicing on creation of Linux systems. Gentoo has excellent setup documentation, for example [about configuring the kernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Installation/Kernel).

And Gentoo is a little easier and faster to setup than Linux From Scratch (LFS). If you want to go deeper, then LFS may be a good learning step too.